# Splitting string in half using C

Tags: c, string, split

How do you split a string in two halves using C? I've looked everywhere for the answer but most seem to deal with splitting at spaces or other characters (examples [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15152744/335858), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7746818/335858), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18420057/335858)).  I just want to split a string into 2 halves. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Sure. Learned math in high school, right?

Comment: Why can't you find split point using strlen()?

Comment: Two halves? `"abcde"` is to be `"abc"` and `"de"` or `"ab"` and `"cde"`? (ignoring `\n`).

Comment: If you know how long the string is (say, _n_), then a copy of the substring from indices [0,n/2) is the first half, and `&string[n/2]` is the second half.

Comment: `    void split(char *s, char **a, char **b) {
       int i = strlen(s) / 2;
       char c = s[i];
       s[i] = 0;
       *a = strdup(s);
       s[i] = c;
       *b = strdup(s + i);
    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no simple way of doing it - it takes several steps:

1. Compute the length of the string
2. Allocate memory for both halves
3. Copy the content into the first half; add null termination
4. Copy the content into the second half; add a null terminator
5. Use your strings
6. Free the first copy
7. Free the second copy

Here is how you can do it:

```
char *str = "quickbrownfox";
int len = strlen(str);
int len1 = len/2;
int len2 = len - len1; // Compensate for possible odd length
char *s1 = malloc(len1+1); // one for the null terminator
memcpy(s1, str, len1);
s1[len1] = '\0';
char *s2 = malloc(len2+1); // one for the null terminator
memcpy(s2, str+len1, len2);
s2[len2] = '\0';
...
free(s1);
free(s2);
```

If you own the entire string, you do not need to make a second copy, because making a pointer into the middle of a string will just work.

Comment: Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/0M5w4U).

Comment: "there's no simple way of doing it" - Um, I'm sure this is considered pretty simple. I'd say trivial.

Comment: @H2CO3 C'mon, spending so many lines of code on a simple pair of `substr`s is not simple - it's almost like we're back to assembly language programming.

Comment: Some say that C is almost like assembly. While I don't agree, I do get the point. My opinion, though, is that this is not what counts as difficult. Creating a complete operating system, writing a 3D engine with heavy maths, coding AI... **That's** what I call difficult. (I don't say that "German language is hard" just because I don't speak German. Surely I could learn it if I wanted. It's all about effort and practice.)

Comment: yea i figured there wouldn't be an easy way like in java or some other language.  thanks this helped

Answer (score 1):

Not if you want to do it in-place. You'd have to sacrifice one character for the `'\0'` byte.

You'll need to think about how you want to allocate memory for the 2nd part of the split string, and code accordingly.